# Maximum principle on noncompact manifold with boundary

Tags: linear-pde, geometric-analysis

On a complete noncompact manifold with ricci curvature bounded below, we have Yau's generalized maximum principle. What if we have we have noncompact manifold with compact boundary and one complete end, do we have a similar maximum principle for a smooth bounded function, namely, at some point p, we obtain the almost maximum with small gradient and hessian.